# Replace Javascript Object in File

Tags: javascript

I have a settings.js file with some config settings, like so:

```
var databaseSettings = {

    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    port: "1000",
    database: "database"

};

exports.apiKey = "12345";
```

What is the best way to overwrite the string values inside the file? For example, if the user were to add a new database name through a UI form, how can I replace the name inside the file?

Comment: using `fs.writeFile()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What environment are you doing this in? A browser? Node.js? Electron? What research have you done to see what your options for writing files are?

Answer (score 1):

For what you're doing, it's best to store and update these types of values in a JSON file. Then you can do the following

```
var fs = require('fs');
var settingsFN = './settings.json';
var settings = require(settingsFN);

file.database = "new value";

fs.writeFile(settingsFN, JSON.stringify(file), function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `settings.js` file that can contain arbitrary code. Use a `settings.json` file, which you can `require()` just as easily but also write by serialising your updated configuration value.